# How to Customise Magento Enterprise Customer Segments?

Tags: enterprise, magento, segments

Do I

1) overide all Enterprise/CustomerSegment

then slot in the classes I need to add my own conditions and classes for models to build the DB queries

2) 1) seems bulky, how would I just add my new condition classes into a local folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to override only the models, and leave the block, controller using Enterprise_CustomerSegment module.

These files would be required to update the CustomerSegment module to add a standing order report:

`CustomModule/CustomerSegment/etc/config.xml`  (with all the model 's)

```
CustomModule/CustomerSegment/Model/Condition/Combine/Abstract.php
```

(this may not need to be overridden)

```
CustomModule/CustomerSegment/Model/Segment/Condition/Combine/Root.php

CustomModule/CustomerSegment/Model/Segment/Condition/Standingorder/Frequency.php

CustomModule/CustomerSegment/Model/Segment/Condition/Combine.php

CustomModule/CustomerSegment/Model/Segment/Condition/Standingorder.php

CustomModule/CustomerSegment/Model/Segment.php
```

(this may not need to be overridden)